# How to apply a DisplayFormatString to columns in a DevExpress ASPxTreeList?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have tried several methods among others that do not seem to work:

```
        ASPxTreeList asdf = new ASPxTreeList();
        (asdf.Columns[0] as TreeListDataColumn).PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "C";
        (asdf.Columns[0] as TreeListTextColumn).PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "{0:C}";
        (asdf.Columns[0] as TreeListDataColumn).DisplayFormat = "{0:C}";
        (asdf.Columns[0] as TreeListTextColumn).DisplayFormat = "C";
```

I still need to try making it a numeric column: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q108195.aspx

I could use the ASPxTreeList.HtmlDataCellPrepared event: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q356689.aspx But I am reserving that as a last resort because it has been slow in the past.

I could create a seperate DataSource and manually format it before databinding but that is also a last resort.

I am not specifically setting any column data types in the DataSource.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you said this "I am not specifically setting any column data types in the DataSource." If you set the data types in the data table and then use:

```
PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "N2";
```

It should work.

Comment: haha.. I just tried that and it worked... I was making a new dataSource based off of the original one and I forgot to set the column types....Thanks for the quick reply!